On a integration test with jUnit/Quarkus how to check a request body of an outgoing http request?
I need to check on one outgoing HTTP call from my service to a known endpoint during an integration test.
I'm using Quarkus, jUnit, Test Containers, and WireMock
My feature runs as follows:

The app receive a request.
It processes and transforms the data it receives

Saves the transformer data on the database


It forward the transformed request to an external endpoint (this endpoint changes based on the request)

Sends a message on kafka, to later execute other processes.


Answer with a 200 [empty body] to the caller

On my integration test I need to validate that on step 3, the process is executing the request with the expected transformations and the right outbound payload on the body.
Some solutions I though for it:

On step 2.1 check if the transformed data is saved as expected on the database.

This works, but it don't validate that the request was sent, and that it was sent to the correct endpoint.


On step 3.1 validate if the message was right on Kafka.

This has the same problem as before



I need a way to intercept the outbound request, and check if it is being sent to the right place and with the right data.
On the answer given on this post (on the second bullet point) they describe the exact way I would want to implement this, but until now, I could not find a feasible way to do it.

You say you are using WireMock, so have you already set this up and configured it with the correct stubs so it will accept requests from your service ?

@LeeTurner Yes, and I already found that I can use the verify from wiremock to check if the endpoint was called. I'm testing and will post an update here sometime in the future.

If you have setup your stubs with Wiremock, then you can use Wiremock.verify.
See also https://wiremock.org/docs/verifying/

Yeah! I found it yesterday, right after posting the question here, I'm still validating if it works as expected, than I'll post an update here. Thanks!
